# Response 500 when sending utf-8

Tags: c#, objective-c, ios, asp.net-mvc-3

When I send a request to my web-service with utf-8 special characters, such as "Ö", it return response 500 "There was an error processing the request" This is what I log in the iOS app.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{    
    NSError *error = nil;

    dict = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:self.responseData error:&error];
    for (id key in dict) {
        NSLog(@"%@=%@", key, [dict objectForKey:key]);
    }
```

If I send a message with just plain english it works fine.

I'm not sure if the error is on the server-side or in the app itself. 
This is how I send my JSON POST:

```
    - (void)stringWithUrl:(NSURL *)url jsonReq:(NSString *)json{

    self.requestURL = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
    self.responseData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[json UTF8String] length:[json length]];


    [self.requestURL setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [self.requestURL setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [self.requestURL setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [self.requestURL setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"UTF-8"];
    [self.requestURL setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [self.responseData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [self.requestURL setHTTPBody: self.responseData];
```

And this is how the web-service look:

```
    ....    
[WebService(Namespace = "http://mypage.com/webservicesF")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX,
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
.....
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
self.responseData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[json UTF8String] length:[json length]];
```

is incorrect. An `NSString`'s length is in UTF-16 characters, not UTF-8 characters. You could do something like:

```
const char* utf8 = [json UTF8String];
self.responseData = [NSData dataWithBytes:utf8 length:strlen(utf8)];
```

but the better way is to just have the string create the `NSData` directly, without going through a C-style string.

```
self.responseData = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

try to encode before send sth like :

```
    NSString *strEncode =  [src stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
```